# Can I use "since" in past simple sentences?

Tags: past-simple

Can I say:

> I didn't see him in Malta since I moved there from Egypt.

Specifically, can I use *since* with past simple?

Comment: You cannot use *since* with a *did/didn't* form. So your sentence is not idiomatic. You can, however use it with the perfect *I have not seen him since Thursday*. The simple past refers to a moment in time, whilst the perfect refers to a period of time.

Answer (score 4):

If you mean "since" in the sense of "after", then no. Since is normally used only with a relative past time, like "I haven't seen him since I moved to Egypt."

You could use "after" to give the same meaning. "I did not see him after I moved to Egypt."

Note that "since" can also mean "because". If you said, "I didn't see him since I moved to Egypt", this would be understood to mean "I didn't see him BECAUSE I moved to Egypt".