Present perfect in the main clause with "since"
I was told that when I use "since" I have to use the perfect tense in the main clause for  instance

I haven't visited her since yesterday

Not

I'm not visiting her since yesterday

Yet I found these examples

You're looking much better since your operation.
She doesn't come round to see us so much since her marriage.
Since last Sunday I can't stop thinking about you.
Things weren't going so well since Father's illness.

Why are 3, 4, 5 and 6 correct? When I don't have to use perfect in the main clause with "since"?
One person says that this sentence "I'm here since Monday" is wrong that I need perfect. On the other hand, here Andrew accepts present continuous
"since" and the tense in the main clause. What's more here   Can I use "since" in past simple sentences?
@Jay says it's wrong if we don't mean "because" but in the previous link, @Andrew accepts present simple and "I didn't see him in Malta since I moved there from Egypt." moved to the present is "I don't see him in Malta since I moved there from Egypt."

"I was told that when I use "since" I have to use the perfect tense in the main clause for instance" Who told you that? Also, why don't you go and look up use of since before posting?

@Lambie. I did. Many sited claim that and online teachers too.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/since Obviously not good ones.

Teachers sometime simplify explanations. I think this "rule" was told me when I was studying English in secondary school, in Italy.

@apaderno tell me something more, please. I'm sure 2 is wrong. So, why the rest if correct?

You need to check when the Present Perfect is used. It is not that when since is used, the Present Perfect is always used.

@Gregor, you keep saying you have done research, but I have not yet seen any evidence of that in the wording of the OP. If you read a sentence that you don't understand, quote it, and give us the reference so we can look it up. If an online teaching guide is confusing you, the same: quote it, and link it. You will find that you get much more help if you do this.

+1 I'm going to give you an upvote, probably my first since I began reading your questions! This shows some research, and the examples explain why you are confused.

@Mari-LouA hahaha. Thank you Mari. I know I'm pain in the a$$

@Gregor, do you understand the difference between an ongoing condition or state,  and an event or action that takes place at a moment in time?

"I'm not speaking to her since yesterday" could mean "We quarrelled yesterday and now we're refusing to talk to one another". Your sentence 2 could possibly mean something like that, but otherwise it doesn't make any sense to use the continuous tense.

@KateBunting What about 3 4 5 and 6

(Sighs) You say yourself that they are correct - they are all cases where it does make sense to use the continuous.

@KateBunting I'd like you to explain when it is correct to use different tenses than perfect ones in th main clause with since

See TimR's comment above! You use the perfect tense for  an action (I have not done [something] since [a certain time]) and other tenses for ongoing situations (I feel much happier since [something happened]).

@KateBunting  https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/166026/can-i-use-since-in-past-simple-sentences  in this link there an example with since (something happened) which is considerded to have been wrong without perfect

If you're writing about the past you normally use past perfect or present perfect in this context. If you're not writing about the past then why would you use a past tense? I think you've misunderstood the rule or been mistaught it, which is why it's good to see where you heard it.

@StuartF why is this correct if the example in my link  is wrong? She doesn't come round to see us so much since her marriage.

The suggested correct version I haven't seen him in Malta since I moved there from Egypt doesn't contradict what I told you. "Seeing him" counts as an action.

@KateBunting I still don't get it. Can you try to explain it differently

There are many usages there that are not directly comparable, but there are two that are parallel, and one works and the other doesn't: "You're looking better since your surgery" and "I'm working here since Monday." I actually started writing an answer and then realized I don't have a sound explanation for why. It might be useful to edit to focus just on those.

The present perfect tense is used for actions that have (or haven't) been performed since a certain time.

I have been to London twice since Christmas.
I have not visited her since yesterday.
I have not eaten since breakfast.

Other tenses can be used for situations which have been ongoing or habitual since a certain time.

She is looking (or looks) better since her operation.
She doesn't visit us so much since her marriage. (habitual)
I feel happier since our talk last week.

